# MonoTorrent - Получение *.torrent из Magnet link'а

Tags: c#, .net, хеширование, torrent

У меня есть хэш торрента (MD5). Вопрос в том, как с помощью MonoTorrent скачать торрент-файл. Это можно сделать с помощью метода из uTorrent API. В смысле не совсем это, потому что он не умеет просто скачивать торрент-файл, он начинает загрузку содержимого. Мне же нужен только список содержимого.

Почти снимает вопрос эта строчка "http://"+"torcache.net/torrent/"
Если прибавить к ней с конца строчку вида "[ХЭШ].torrent" и перейти по этой ссылке в браузере, то скачивается нужный файл. Но если сделать то же с помощью

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
wc.DownloadFile("http://"+"torcache.net/torrent/[HASH].torrent", @"[PATH]");
}
```

то тоже скачивается *.torrent, но почему-то не закодированный. uTorrent его не может прочитать, выдаёт ошибку "Torrent Is Not Valid Bencoding".

Всё должно работать примерно так и files должен содержать то, что нужно

```
ClientEngine engine;
EngineSettings settings = new EngineSettings();

string hash = @"163B5E7C7D22B57E26DCC6DA5951104453769E61";
string magnet = string.Format("magnet:?xt=urn:btih:{0}", hash);
MagnetLink ml = new MagnetLink(magnet);
TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(ml1,
                [ПУТЬ СОХРАНЕНИЯ],
                new TorrentSettings(),
                [ПУТЬ К ТОРРЕНТУ]);
engine.Register(manager);
manager.Start();

List<TorrentFile> files = manager.Torrent.Files.ToList();
```

Однако files оказывается пуст. Вероятно, не работает конструктор MagnetLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено благодаря ошибке uTorrent.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using fh = FileHelpers;
using UTorrent.Api;
using UT = UTorrent;
using MonoTorrent.Client;
using MonoTorrent.Client.Encryption;
using MonoTorrent.Common;

namespace csvTorrent {
class Program {
    private static string path1 = @"A:\torrents\category_8";
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var engine = new fh.FileHelperEngine<MyTorrents>();
        var res = engine.ReadFile(path1 + ".csv");
        string magHead = @"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:";
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++) {
            UT.Api.UTorrentClient UTC = new UTorrentClient("admin", "admin");
            UTC.AddUrlTorrent(magHead + res[i]._hash, @"c:\torrents");
            UTC.RecheckTorrent(magHead + res[i]._hash);
            k++;
            if (k == 20) {
                Console.ReadLine();
                k = 0;
            }
        }

        string torrentsPath = @"C:\torrents";

        ClientEngine monoEngine;

        EngineSettings settings = new EngineSettings();
        settings.AllowedEncryption = EncryptionTypes.All;
        settings.SavePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "torrents");

        if (!Directory.Exists(settings.SavePath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(settings.SavePath);

        monoEngine = new ClientEngine(settings);
        monoEngine.Settings.SavePath = @"C:\torrents";

        List<string> _torrents = new List<string>();
        _torrents = Directory.EnumerateFiles(torrentsPath).ToList();
        foreach (string s in _torrents) {
            Torrent torrent = Torrent.Load(s);
            TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(torrent,
            @"C:\torrents",
            new TorrentSettings(),
            @"C:\torrents");

            monoEngine.Register(manager);

            manager.Start();

            List<TorrentFile> files = manager.Torrent.Files.ToList();
            using (TextWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"A:\torrents\hashes.txt")) {
                foreach (TorrentFile file in files) {
                    sw.WriteLine(file.Path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//"ForumId форума";"Название форума";"ForumId раздачи";"Info hash";"Название раздачи";"Размер в байтах","Дата регистрации торрента"
[fh.DelimitedRecordAttribute(";")]
class MyTorrents {
    public string _forumId;
    public string _forumName;
    public string _torrentId;
    public string _hash;
    public string _torrentName;
    public string _size;
    public string date;
}
}
```